# Resize any image to 512 x 512

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, stable-diffusion

I am trying to train a stable diffusion model, which receives `512 x 512` images as inputs.

I am downloading the bulk of images from the web, and they have multiple sizes and shapes, and so I need to preprocess them and convert to `512 x 512`.

If I take this `2000 × 1434` image:

[image]

And I try to resize it, with:

```
from PIL import Image

# Open an image file
with Image.open("path/to/Image.jpg") as im:
    # Create a thumbnail of the image
    im.thumbnail((512, 512))
    # Save the thumbnail
    im.save("path/to/Image_resized.jpg")
```

I get this `512 × 367` image:

[image]

But I need 512 for both width and height, ***without distorting the image***, like you can achieve on this website:

[Birma](https://www.birme.net/)

Any ideas on how I can achieve this conversion using python?

Comment: You have to crop the image. Resize the short dimension (in the example  1434px) to 512px and crop the other dimension 714px by 202px.

Comment: if you answer with a workable code, I'll gladly accept and upvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think a resize of an image with another aspect ratio of 1:1 (512:512) is possible without distorting the image. You can resize the shorter dimension of the image to 512px and crop the large dimension to 512px.

```
from PIL import Image

# Open an image file
with Image.open("image.jpg") as im:
    width, height = im.size
    if width < height:
        newWidth = 512
        newHeight = int(height / (width / 512))
        cropTop = (newHeight - 512) // 2
        cropBottom = cropTop + 512
        crop = (0, cropTop, 512, cropBottom)
    else:
        newHeight = 512
        newWidth = int(width / (height / 512))
        cropLeft = (newWidth - 512) // 2
        cropRight = cropLeft + 512
        crop = (cropLeft, 0, cropRight, 512)
    imResize = im.resize((newWidth, newHeight))
    imCrop = imResize.crop(crop)
    imCrop.save("image_resized_cropped.jpg")
```